# Meteor user profile can only read after refresh

Tags: meteor

for user data, I have a publish/subscribe that looks like this:

```
Meteor.publish("allUserData", function () {
    return Meteor.users.find({}, {
            fields: { "emails": 1, "_id": 1, "profile": 1 }
        }
    );
});

Meteor.subscribe("allUserData");
```

But, when I try to read the profile, it's always undefined until I refresh the page, then I can read it.
I'm trying to read the profile as follows:

```
Meteor.user().profile
```

What am I doing wrong? Why does it work when I refresh the page, but not on initial load?  I've tried the property names in the publish function with and without quotes...

Comment: Could you give a bit of code on the portion you're using to read the user's profile?

Comment: I guess what I was asking was could you give some info on how you're using `Meteor.user().profile` in what context? If you wait a bit before you refresh does it help? Is this on your localhost?

Comment: Yes, i needed to wait a bit.  I don't understand why, but that fixed my issue...  thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Meteor.user().profile isn't available until a fraction of a second after Meteor.user() is. Also, when a user account is created it does not have a profile. The solution is to use a timeout in a reactive function.

```
Meteor.autorun(function(handle) {
  if (Meteor.user()) {
    if (Meteor.user().profile) {
      // use profile
      handle.stop()
    }
    else {
      setTimeout(function(){
        if (!Meteor.user().profile) {
          // new user - first time signing in
          Meteor.users.update(Meteor.userId(), {
            $set: {
              'profile.some_attribute': some_value
            }
          })
        }
      }, 2000)
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: I didn't know this about the profile.  Why is it not available immediately?  Also, for my particular situation, I was passing a profile property into a subscribe method, so wrapping that subscribe in Meteor.autosubscribe caused the subscription to work, fixing my issue.

Comment: Oh I see. Yeah autosubscribe may be more appropriate in your situation. The important thing is to use a reactive function. I suspect profile is not available immediately because it can grow to become arbitrarily large, and thus could delay the client significantly from retrieving _id and emails.

Comment: Autosubscribe got deprecated today. If you upgrade to 0.5.5 use autorun instead.

Comment: Yeah, I just saw that!  Thanks for the heads up!